# How to implement 16 bit->32 bit lookup table in ARM assembly using NEON?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, assembly, arm

In an iOS 6 project, I have a buffer containing two byte words (16 bits) that need to be translated to four byte words (32 bits) via a lookup table. I hard-code the values into the table, and then use the the value of the two byte buffer to determine which 32 bit table value to retrieve. Here's an example:

```
void map_values(uint32_t *dst,uint16_t *src,uint32_t *lut,int buf_length){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<buf_length;i++){

        *dst = *(lut+(*src));
        dst++;
        src++;
    }
}
```

The problem is, it's too slow. Could this be sped up by processing 4 output bytes at a time using NEON? The thing is, I'm iffy on how to take the value from the src buffer and use that as an input to the lookup table to figure out what value to retrieve. Also, the word lengths are the same in the table and the output buffer, but not for the source. So, I can only read two 16 bit words as input, versus the four 32 bit word output I need. Any ideas? Is there a better way to approach this problem, perhaps?

Current asm output from clang (clang -O3 -arch armv7 lut.c -S):

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .section    __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
    .section    __TEXT,__const_coal,coalesced
    .section    __TEXT,__picsymbolstub4,symbol_stubs,none,16
    .section    __TEXT,__StaticInit,regular,pure_instructions
    .syntax unified
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _map_values
    .align  2
    .code   16                      @ @map_values
    .thumb_func _map_values
_map_values:
@ BB#0:
    cmp r3, #0
    it  eq
    bxeq    lr
LBB0_1:                                 @ %.lr.ph
                                        @ =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    ldrh    r9, [r1], #2
    subs    r3, #1
    ldr.w   r9, [r2, r9, lsl #2]
    str r9, [r0], #4
    bne LBB0_1
@ BB#2:                                 @ %._crit_edge
    bx  lr


.subsections_via_symbols
```

Comment: There are two problems. The first is that you need 2 indirections to get to your value. The second is that you'll jump all over a 64k big array, this is going to trash you're cache left and right. For testing purposes you could limit the values in *src to 8bit values, I guess you'll see a drastic increase in speed. Neon MIGHT help, because IIRC it has a direct path to the L2 cache, which is usually bigger than 256k and should be able to hold the complete array. You should post the currently generated assembly.

Comment: The assembly looks ok (under these circumstances). Loopunrolling might help, but that depends on the length of your input data. If you can assure its always len%4==0 or len%8 == 0 then you can hide nearly all load latencies. But still, your lut will not fit the l1 cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookup tables are (nearly) unvectorizable.  Very small lookup tables can be handled with the `vtbl` instruction, but your lookup table is far too big for that.

What are you using the lookup table for?  If the values can be computed on the fly without too much work instead of looking them up, that may actually be a significant win for you.

Comment: I need to convert a 16 bit RGB image to 32 bit RGBA. So, the input image is half the data as the output image. In other words, 16 bits per RGB input versus 32 bits for RGBA output.

Comment: What is the 16b format?  It is likely that the conversion is already implemented for you in the vImage sub framework of Accelerate.

Comment: Accelerate has vImageConvert_RGB565toARGB8888, which *almost* gets you what you want.  You could roll your own neon-based conversion (without a lookup table), or you could use a two-pass algorithm where you use the vImage routine and then simply do the ARGB --> RGBA permute in NEON, which should still be quite fast, if slightly ugly.  You should also file a bug to request the conversion you want.

Comment: The key thing is that the conversion can be done *much* faster using vectorized arithmetic than it can using a lookup table.

Comment: I tried vImageConvert_RGB565toARGB8888() and it works pretty well! Much faster than the lookup table. However, as you pointed out the colors are wrong. I'll try the NEON intrinsics to see if I can swizzle the colors.

Comment: Vltb could be used for r&b conversion, but it just might be overkill, as one just need to copy 3 (or 2 for green) msbs in the lower bits.

Comment: In X.9 and iOS 7.0, we added vImageConvert_RGB565toRGBA8888, which will put the colors in the desired order.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that you might get some luck out of `vtablelookup` in the vecLib portion of the [Accelerate](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vecLib/Reference/reference.html) framework. The signature is:

```
vUInt32 vtablelookup (
   vSInt32 Index_Vect,
   uint32_t *Table
);
```

where `vSInt32` and `vUInt32` are 128 bit packed 32 bit signed/unsigned integers respectively. I believe the function is backed by NEON on ARM. The big problem will be converting your `src` array into 32 bit indices, which could well slow things down so much as to render the speed gains from vectorising the lookup pointless.